# Statsmodels OLS terms undefined

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to do a basic linear regression example and I have an example dataset with sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width.  However, in my R forumla if I try anything with more terms than `"sepal_length ~ petal_length"` like `"sepal_length ~ petal_length + sepal_width + petal_width"` I get  the error `NameError: name 'sepal_width' is not defined`  This happens with any term where I use the `+` operator to add a third column from the dataset. The columns work if I add them independently.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
irises = pd.read_csv("data/iris.csv")
model1 = sm.OLS.from_formula("sepal_length ~ petal_length", data=irises).fit()
print(model1.summary())
xs = pd.DataFrame({'petal_length': np.linspace(irises.petal_length.min(), irises.petal_length.max(), 100)})
ys = model1.predict(xs)
sns.scatterplot(x='petal_length', y='sepal_length', data=irises)
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='black', linewidth=4)
plt.show()
```

For example,

this works:

`model1 = sm.OLS.from_formula("sepal_length ~ petal_length", data=irises).fit()`

this doesn't work:

`model1 = sm.OLS.from_formula("sepal_length ~ petal_length + sepal_width", data=irises).fit()`

I get the error sepal_width is not defined. And I get the same error for any term I add like this.

but this does work:

`model1 = sm.OLS.from_formula("sepal_length ~ sepal_width", data=irises).fit()`

and so does this:

`model1 = sm.OLS.from_formula("sepal_length ~ petal_length + np.power(petal_length, 2)", data=irises).fit()`

In essence I'm trying to use more than two independent variables in `sm.OLS.from_formula`.

Comment: What are the column names in your `irises` dataframe?

Comment: sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, and species.

Answer (score 1):

Try import statsmodels.api as sm, I got it working.
[image: example]

Comment: The problem I'm having is using more than just two independent variables in OLS.from_formula

Comment: I got it still working, check versions of sm, numpy and pandas. Try updating to latest versions. pip install -U statsmodels pandas numpy